# CSS div height percentage with margin percentage

Tags: css

I have a relative div with percentage height and margin.

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>

.a{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

.b{
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    height:75%;
    width:92%;
    margin: 25% 4% 0 4%;
}
```

Height 75% and margin-top 25% should add up to 100%. But, it is not cover all the height of the parent.

This is what I want:
[image]
This is what I get:
[image]

see fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hc3L7ynf/2/

Comment: I think i found the answer : http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-box-3/#the-margin-properties

Comment: Note that in a horizontal flow, percentages on ‘margin-top’ and ‘margin-bottom’ are relative to the width of the containing block, not the height (and in vertical flow, ‘margin-left’ and ‘margin-right’ are relative to the height, not the width).

Comment: You should use padding instead of margin. And also margin-top or margin-bottom or padding-top or padding-bottom in percentage is respective to the width of the container but not height.

Comment: thanks Mr_Green, I got the clue. I think it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Position Tricky

Changing your fixed position to absolute makes it easier to show what the problem is:

```css
.a{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.b{
    position: relative;
    background-color:red;
    height:75%;
    width:92%;
    margin: 25% 4% 0% 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

The easiest fix is just adding a class above it with height: 25%;
or using a the ::before would do the same thing.

```css
.a {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.b {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 75%;
}
.c {
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I want, thanks for suggestion using ::before. I will try that, so i don't need to change the html.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of margin using padding.

```
.b{
position:relative;
background-color:red;
height:75%;
width:92%;
padding: 25% 4% 0 4%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hc3L7ynf/3/)

Comment: sorry, but this is not what i wanted. I want the child size is some percent of the parent, and stick at the bottom center.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fiddle example. What you want can be created with

```
.b {
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    height:96%;
    width:92%;
    margin: 4% 4% 0% 4%;
}
```

Comment: what i want is to keep the relative div (`.b`) at the bottom, using combination `margin-top`+`height`=100%. But from the fiddle example, there is some space in the bottom.